# 3 vertical points between three equations that are lined up

Tags: equations, align, vertical-alignment, alignment, eqnarray

I'm trying to put vertical lines between the equations, but I can't do it. Here's my MWE.

```
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &= f_1&(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)\\
\vdots & &\vdots \\
\frac{dx_i}{dt} &= f_i&(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)\\
\vdots & &\vdots \\
\frac{dx_n}{dt} &= f_n&(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)
\end{align}
```

The dots are not in the right place. I want centered dots in both sides.

[image: displaye]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic word is `\vdotswithin{...}`. It horizontally centers `\vdots` in a box of the same width as `...`.
[image: Result]
Note that the `\vdots` in the first column are centered within the `=` which I consider better than within the whole expression.

Furthermore I'd recommend to not number the even lines (`\nonumber`). And there is another version of `\vdotswithin`, namely `\shortvdotswithin`, but this will cause a linebreak and therefore you cannot use it in this case, unless you don't use the workaround described in the [`mathtools` documentation](https://kebo.pens.ac.id/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \newlength{\mylengthA} \settowidth{\mylengthA}{$\dfrac{dx_i}{dt}$}
    \begin{align}
        \frac{dx_1}{dt} &= f_1           & &(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)               \\
                        &\vdotswithin{=} & &\vdotswithin{(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)} \\
        \frac{dx_i}{dt} &= f_i           & &(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)               \\
                        &\vdotswithin{=} & &\vdotswithin{(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)} \\
        \frac{dx_n}{dt} &= f_n           & &(x_1,\dots,x_i, x_n)
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```